# Rails: How to loop through request.headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

#### How can I loop through `request.headers`?

Looping through with `each` in a view doesn't work. I've also tried the `to_hash` method which also fails.

#### Examples of what I've been trying to do

**View Hash in JSON**

For an echo action, I have a jbuilder template in which I want to print all request headers with:

```
json.request_headers request.headers
```

This gives me: `ActionView::Template::Error (not opened for reading)`. The same works flawlessly for the `params` hash.

#### Logging keys and values

Then, in the echo controllers I did this:

```
incr=0
request.headers.each do |key, value|
    logger.debug "Header #{ incr }: #{ key }, #{ value }"
    incr += 1
end
```

which gives me some HTTP headers but also some rack and action_dispatch information such as `Header 17: rack.version, [1, 3]` or `Header 32: action_dispatch.parameter_filter, [:password]` which I'm not interested in and I guess gives me the above error (file not opened for reading).

#### Additional Question

Also, in my search I couldn't find any hint what (kind of object?) exactely `request.headers` is. What is an easy way to figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

All standard and custom headers start with HTTP.  This does the trick for me:

```
request.headers.each {|key,value| 
  logger.debug "#{key}='#{value}'" if key.start_with? "HTTP"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **response.headers** is a Hash. You can read more about the response [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object). Since it's a Hash it should respond to `.each`, if it does not, you should update your question with the error you're getting.

Also, note that you can always call `.class` on an object to find it's type.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake, I'm talking about **request**.headers, of course. The response.headers works fine. Thank you for the hint on finding the class of an object.

Comment: Well, the same applies to request.headers, that's also a Hash.

Comment: I added some examples above. After some research, I guess the correct question would be "How can I _easily_ print the request.header hash content in a view?" Is there a way to "precreate" the header so all content is available in the view? Simply creating a new variable from request.headers doesn't work. I will update the question once it's clear what the problem exactely was.